# How to make a user set variable, then place it in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a travel website for a school project, and for the purchase part, I need to use functions to see what package the customer chooses and then display the price. But I seem to have issues getting the variables or the `onclick` working.

```js
function userSetPack(uInput) {
  var input = document.getElementById("uInput").value;
  document.getElementById('cost').innerHTML = 'input';
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Select list</label>
  
  <select id="myList">
    <option onclick="userSetPack(uInput)" id="One" value="1">Package One </option>
    <option onclick="userSetPack(uInput)" id="Two" value="2">Package Two</option>
    <option onclick="userSetPack(uInput)" id="Three" value="3">Package Three</option>
  </select>

  <button onclick="userSetPack(uInput)">Submit</button>
</form>

<p id="cost"></p>
```

I am very new to JS so I truly have no clue if this is correct, I gathered up this info from SoloLearn and StackOverflow posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally don't use inline javascript like `onclick` and you never use it on an `option` element, as this will not work. What you should be doing is to listen to change on the select element. Furthermore, there's no element named `uInput` in your html.

```js
document.getElementById('myList').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  document.getElementById('cost').innerText = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Select list</label>
  <select id="myList">
    <option id="One" value="1">Package One </option>
    <option id="Two" value="2">Package Two</option>
    <option id="Three" value="3">Package Three</option>
  </select>
</form>
<p id="cost"> </p>
```

Comment: thank you! works like a charm. now I can finally add on the person counter for the prices. just one question. if it targets the values, how do I make the values the prices and other things. is it possible to do like e.target.id(x).write.("var + text)? or no.

Answer (score 2):

You should attach the event to select's *onchange* attribute. Also it is better to use `innerText` or `textContent` when the string is not *htmlString*.

Try the following way:

```js
function userSetPack(uInput) {
  var input = uInput.value;
  document.getElementById('cost').textContent = input;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Select list</label>
  <select id="myList" onchange="userSetPack(this)">
    <option id="One" value="1">Package One </option>
    <option id="Two" value="2">Package Two</option>
    <option id="Three" value="3">Package Three</option>
  </select>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<p id="cost"> </p>
```

Though the preferred solution will be avoiding inline events and using `addEventListener` and *click* event like the following way:

```js
document.getElementById('myList').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var input = this.value;
  document.getElementById('cost').textContent = input;
});
document.getElementById('myList').click();
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Select list</label>
  <select id="myList">
    <option id="One" value="1">Package One </option>
    <option id="Two" value="2">Package Two</option>
    <option id="Three" value="3">Package Three</option>
  </select>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<p id="cost"> </p>
```

Comment: Downvoted for recommending using inline javascript.

Comment: Also, the js to do `onchange` should be in quotes.

Comment: @tanmay_garg No. It shouldn't be there at all

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this, and It will looks like clean your `HTML` code.

```js
  function userSetPack(){
    var input = document.getElementById("myList").value;
    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = input;
  }
```

```html
  <form>
     <label>Select list</label>
    <select id="myList" onchange="userSetPack()">
      <option value="1">Package One</option>
      <option value="2">Package Two</option>
      <option value="3">Package Three</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="userSetPack()">Submit</button>
  </form>
   <p id="cost"></p>
```